# New deploy with django and zappa only returns the error "NoneType object has no attribute read"

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, zappa

I've been using Django + zappa + aws perfectly for a few years now. However, when trying to deploy a new project using the latest versions of Django(4.2.1) and zappa(0.56.1) the project deploy only returns:

*"Error: Warning! Status check on the deployed lambda failed. A GET request to '/' yielded a 500 response code."*

And using the zappa tail command just returns:

*"NoneType object has no attribute read"*

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://github.com/zappa/Zappa/issues/1230 where this issue is logged and there is a workaround.

Comment: Include the workaround in your post so that if ever the link is dead, your post still makes sense

Answer (score 0):

The last released version 0.57.0 fixes this error.
If you run `pip install 'zappa>=0.57.0'` you should get the fixed release.

Full release notes: https://github.com/zappa/Zappa/releases/tag/0.57.0